# Google Charts Tooltip

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I am using a Google Pie Chart in my website to show some data of company expenses. The chart gives me nice tooltips as I hover over the slices. It says for example 27% and gives the number of expense as 522552225.00 for example. What I would like to do is to get the number formatted as it is hard to read when the number is large. I would like to have this instead 522,552,225.00.

The problem is that the number comes from database.

Is there a solution to this?

Thanks!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ["Label","Value"],
          <?php echo $MyDataArrayAsString; ?>
        ]);

        var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({pattern:'#,###.00'});
        // format column 1 of DataTable "data"
        formatter.format(data, 2);

        var options = {"width":<?php echo $params->get('width')?>,
                       "height":<?php echo $params->get('height')?>, 
                       "tooltip": {"trigger": '<?php echo $params->get('tooltip')?>' },
                    };

        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('donutchart'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }

</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a [NumberFormatter](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#numberformatter) on the appropriate DataTable column:

```
var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({pattern: '#,###.00'});
// format column 1 of DataTable "data"
formatter.format(data, 1);
```

Comment: Ok, asgallant, thanks for your answer, I think it should be correct, but I do not manage to use it in my code. I edited my question with the code and if I put everything like this, it shows me nothing. Do you see where the problem is?

Comment: Your DataTable only has two columns of data, so calling `formatter.format(data, 2);` won't do anything.  Columns are zero-indexed, so the "Label" column in 0 and the "Value" column is 1.  Use `formatter.format(data, 1);` as I posted in my answer.

Comment: Thanks, I tried with both but it did not work for another reason, your answer is right.

Comment: Correct the `pattern: #,###.00` to **`pattern: '#,###.00'`** and this will work well.

Comment: Thanks for catching the typo; I fixed the answer.